# Were the London Bridge attack victims Londoners?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

From ABC News: [London police chief: Attack victims show city's diversity](http://abcnews.go.com/International/wireStory/london-police-chief-attack-victims-show-citys-diversity-47955375) (The [tweet for the article](https://twitter.com/ABC/status/873636522838421504) had 2.4K replies, and some replies had thousands of likes)

> The commissioner of London's Metropolitan Police says the
>   nationalities of the eight victims in the terrorist attack on London
>   Bridge tell a proud story of London's unique makeup.
>
> "It's desperately sad and poignant but among those who died is someone
>   who's British, there are French, Australian, Canadian, Spanish,"
>   Cressida Dick told The Associated Press in an interview Saturday.
>
> "In terms of our witnesses that we've spoken to so far, out of the
>   300-odd people, there are about 20 different countries of origin. And
>   the London British population comes from all kinds of backgrounds and
>   every kind of faith and ethnicity."
>
> She said longtime Londoners value this international aspect of the
>   British capital.
>
> "We believe of course that that's what makes our city so great," she
>   said. "It's a place where the vast majority of time it's incredibly
>   integrated and that diversity gives us strength."

Some have disputed this, suggesting that the victims were tourists rather than Londoners. An example tweet said

> What? the attack on the iconic London bridge was an attack on our TOURIST trade. Tourists are mostly foreign, Dick.

Were the victims of the attacks Londoners?

Comment: Isn't it more or less universally true that people who visit tourist attractions are tourists rather than natives?  I include recent immigrants and people temporarily working in the country as tourists.

Comment: @jamesqf would you prefer the question ask if the victims were Londoners?

Comment: @jamesqf I've edited the question.

Comment: @gerrit I've edited the question.

Comment: Sounds like whoever wrote that tweet is making the old mistake of mixing up Tower Bridge (the iconic world-famous bridge and major tourist destination) with London Bridge (an important but comparatively ordinary road bridge in an area with a few tourists but mostly dominated by offices, business-oriented bars and restaurants and commuters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At least one of the victims was a tourist, but several others were either foreigners or immigrants and were living in London at the time of the attack. For three of the nationalities mentioned by Dick (French, Australian, and Spanish) there were individuals living and working in London, and the Canadian had moved from Canada to somewhere in Europe.

From [London attack: The victims](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-40153090)

- Ignacio Echeverria was from Madrid, Spain and was working for HSBC bank in London.
- Xavier Thomas was French and was visiting the capital. The article [Family pays tribute to French tourist killed in London Bridge attack](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2017/jun/09/xavier-thomas-family-pays-tribute-french-tourist-killed-london-bridge-attack) explicitly states that he was a tourist.
- Sebastien Belanger was French, and worked at Coq d'Argent near Bank. The article implies it's in London, and the [restaurant's website](http://www.coqdargent.co.uk/) confirms this, having London in its address.
- Sara Zelenak was Australian, and was working as an au pair in London.
- Kirsty Boden was Australian, and working in the UK as a senior staff nurse.
- Chrissy Archibald was Canadian, and had moved to Europe.
- James McMullan was from Hackney, London.
- Alexandre Pigeard was a French national, and had been working in Borough Market for nine months.

Comment: The [Mayor of Castlegar suggested](http://news.nationalpost.com/news/canada/christine-archibald-killed-in-london-terror-attack) Chrissy Archibald was living in Amsterdam with her fiancé, but they were in London temporarily because he had work there (Castlegar being her home town in Canada)